# Static linked list look up in python

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a function that can look up a value in a statically linked list in Python. I have already written a function to do this for a dynamically linked list, but not sure how to go about changing it for static. How can I do this?

My function to look up a value in a dynamically linked list is:

```
def lookup(self,name):
    if len(self.dictstack) > 0:
        var = '/' + name
        for i in range(len(self.dictstack)-1, -1, -1): 
            if var in self.dictstack[i]:
                return self.dictstack[i].get(var)

        raise ValueError('Error: lookup - no variable or function found')
    else:
       print("Error: lookup - Dictionary stack is empty")
```

Comment: What does static vs dynamic mean in this case?

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about what you mean by static vs. dynamic linked lists. I've never heard of such a distinction (and web searches for it tend to get results for static vs dynamic linked libraries).

Comment: What is a static linked list?

Comment: By the way is it really a linked list? Probably I am wrong, usually I expect a recursive logic when it comes to a linked list, but I don't see any...

Comment: There is no linked list in your code. Since you access elements with direct indexing (`[i]`), your code is (likely) dealing with lists, not linked lists.